# Cómo convertir una cadena de texto a un número en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una cadena tal que así '10,5'. Está en el sistema decimal español donde la coma es el separador decimal. Al tratar de hacer la conversión con la función cast, me devuelve un error de conversión de tipos, lo cual es lógico. Lo que hago es utilizar la función Replace para sustituir la coma por el punto y de ese modo poder hacer la conversión correctamente, pero he visto que tanto las funciones cast y convert disponen de una claúsula collate que quizá me ayude, pero parece ser que solo es aplicable con tipos de char y no numéricos. ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacer esta conversión sin emplear la función replace?

Para que quede claro os detallo la expresión que uso:

```
cast(replace('10,5',',','.') as float)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir de la versión 2014, puedes usar la función [`PARSE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) que tiene el parámetro opcional `culture`:

```
SELECT PARSE('10,5' AS NUMERIC(15,2)  USING 'es-ES')
```

También tienes la variante `TRY_PARSE()` que no genera un error, solo retornará `NULL` en este caso.

Comment: Gracias Patricio. Try_parse ya la había probado pero no me sirve ya que devuleve Null, lo mejor es lo que tú dices.